# Undefined index error, how can I solve this?

Tags: indexing

This is my full coding,

```
<?php
```

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

```
if($username && $password){
            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$username', '$password')");

            $msg = "User is created successfully";
    }
    else{
            $error = "Please fillup all required fields!";
    }
```

}
?>

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="settings_user.php" method="POST">

                            <div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label">User Name</label>

                                <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="" class="form-control" autofocus> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="form-control"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit">ADD</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php echo $msg; ?>
                            <?php echo $error; ?>

                    </form>
```

two error message appears: Undefined index for $msg and $error

how can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, it should appear, Because the variable $msg and $error will be defined only if the form is submitted !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. Instead of using 2 variables for "success" and "failure", use single variable and put the message accordingly. Initialize the variable globally.

```
<?php
 $msg="";
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


 $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password'];
 if($username && $password){
 $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$username', '$password')");

 $msg = "User is created successfully";
 }
 else{
 $msg = "Please fillup all required fields!";
 }
 } 

 ?>

 <html>
 <body>
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="settings_user.php" method="POST">
 <div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label">User Name</label>
 <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="" class="form-control"         

 autofocus> 
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
 <div class="col-lg-4"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="form-  

 control"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit">ADD</button>
 </div>
 </div>

 <?php echo $msg; ?>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```